# Can I use "worse, worst" instead of "badder, baddest"?

Tags: meaning

In Collins Dictionary, under bad, it says that

BAD 15 :
Word forms: badder or baddest
(slang)
good; excellent

But in this meaning, can I use “worse, worst” instead of “badder, baddest”?

Comment: *Ooh! - You are **awful**!* I don't think I've ever encountered this kind of "slang semantic inversion" with ***worse, worst***. But I'm an ole fart, so I think ***badder, baddest = better, best*** just sounds stupid anyway.

Comment: No, worse and worst would not convey the same meaning.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79183/is-baddest-a-proper-word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Bad* in the sense of *good* is like *badass.*

Worse does not work in this sense, *except* when referring to a person ironically such as, "Oh, John, *you are just **the worst***."

That would mean that John is, for example, satirically witty and actually quite charming, but slightly daring in his behavior.

But on the whole, "bad" in the sense of "good" does not continue the "worse, worst" pattern.